# windows web-scraping encoding error: a non-major undergraduate, don't know what to do

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pycharm, anaconda

this is the first time I use this platform so I might not know the rule here. But here is my proble:
I signed up for a course lecturing web-scraping using python, the teacher uses MacOS but I use windows.
he gave us this py article to stretch information from a job website, and it worked perfectly fine in his computer- not mine.
The error code is this:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 3452: illegal multibyte sequence
Process finished with exit code 1

I googled this error code several times with different lines of code applied, but the same problem continues to pop up. I barely know anything about computer programming, as a political science student, so I suspect if I put the correct code in the wrong place (I put them at the bottom). Here are some examples:

```
`print(r.text['response'][i].replace(u'\xa0 ', u' '))`

`self.file.write(content.replace(u'\xa0', u''))`

self.file.write(content.encode("gbk", 'ignore').decode("gbk", "ignore"))

self.file = open('biaobai.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
```

self.file.write(content)

The original code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 _*-

class HKJob(object):
def __init__(self, page):
    # init logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='HKJob.log', level=logging.INFO)
    self.page = page
    self.url = 'https://hk.jobsdb.com/hk/en/Search/FindJobs?JSRV=1&page=' + str(page)
    print('Working on page ' + str(page))
    self.header ``{'accept':text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        # 'cookie': '__cfduid=d4a5e5025c307a0899cfb595f591de2321591411627; __cfduid=d4a5e5025c307a0899cfb595f591de2321591411627; azTest=j%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22af644b3a-7e57-4b74-a6ac-7081d2f3c78e%22%2C%22createdAt%22%3A%222020-06-06T00%3A46%3A43.809Z%22%7D; ABNEWHP=1607; showNewHomePage=B; isSmartSearch=A; sol_id=74034b65-7d37-43de-94e1-ea2caf21d6dc; s_fid=47BC437B5DDD3E34-38816260845AF8DB; _gcl_au=1.1.3255028.1591411635; s_vi=[CS]v1|2F6D81D905159C2C-60000A22221F80DA[CE]; intercom-id-o7zrfpg6=489c6e71-c371-4a82-9478-26f4afa57525; _fbp=fb.1.1591411666764.1130609656; s_cc=true; _hjid=533d3b03-b258-4c44-b361-6b35adae2f01; RecentSearch=%7B%22Keyword%22%3A%5B%22data%22%5D%7D; ABSSRPGroup=B; ABHPGroup=B; ABJDGroup=B; NSC_wjq_kpctec.dpn_ttm=30dfa3dbcdc234aa83959421623161a99f20596b3402b72e8d156af38c20a8f9e3dee830; ABIDPGroup=1; sol_id_pre_stored=74034b65-7d37-43de-94e1-ea2caf21d6dc; _gid=GA1.2.818155812.1593870501; intercom-session-o7zrfpg6=; ASP.NET_SessionId=rronrppqvou1gjrlcpebyl5g; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; ABSSRP=1659; sol_id=74034b65-7d37-43de-94e1-ea2caf21d6dc; utag_main=v_id:017287866ed70010221858819c4c03078007207000bd0$_sn:5$_se:2$_ss:0$_st:1593915998514$ses_id:1593914193762%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session; _ga=GA1.1.960239391.1591411635; _ga_88RH71GXX9=GS1.1.1593914191.5.1.1593914314.0',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

def send_get_request(self, url):
    # 3. Receive Response
    r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
    if r.text:
        response = r.text
        # print('get response success')
        return response
    else:
        print('get response fail')
        return ''

def extract_info_urls(self, response):
    # The response is not json this time. We need to extract information from html file.
    # Therefore, we need to import a new module -- lxml
    # Please review how to install new module using conda, we discussed it in the first session.
    raw_tree = etree.HTML(response)
    # Here we first extract the urls of the detailed info pages
    job_urls = raw_tree.xpath(
        '//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h1/a/@href')
    return job_urls

# 4. Extract Information
def extract_information(self, response):
    raw_tree = etree.HTML(response)
    dict_result = {}
    dict_result['job_name'] = raw_tree.xpath(
        '//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/h1/text()')[
        0]
    dict_result['company_name'] = raw_tree.xpath(
        '//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span/text()')[
        0]
    try:
        dict_result['company_img'] = raw_tree.xpath(
            '//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/img/@src')[0]
    except IndexError:
        dict_result['company_img'] = ''
    try:
        dict_result['work_place'] = raw_tree.xpath(
            '//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/a/span/text()')[
            0]
    except IndexError:
        dict_result['work_place'] = ''
    try:
        dict_result['salary'] = raw_tree.xpath(
            '//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span/text()')[0]
    except IndexError:
        dict_result['salary'] = ''
    dict_result['posted_time'] = raw_tree.xpath(
        '//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/span/text()')[0]

    dict_result['job_details'] = '\n'.join(
        raw_tree.xpath('//*[@id="contentContainer"]/div/div[2]/div/descendant::*/text()'))
    dict_result['page'] = self.page
    return dict_result

def save_information(self, raw_json):
    with open('HKJob_result.json', 'a+') as out_f:
        out_f.write(json.dumps(raw_json, ensure_ascii=False) + '\n')

def run(self):
    response = self.send_get_request(self.url)
    job_urls = self.extract_info_urls(response)
    for url in job_urls:
        try:
            print('Scraping url ' + url)
            info_response = self.send_get_request(url)
            raw_json = self.extract_information(info_response)
            raw_json['job_url'] = url
            # self.save_information_json(raw_json)
            self.save_information(raw_json)
        except IndexError as e:
            print('There are something wrong when phrasing ' + url)
            logging.info(str(e) + ' ' + url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which python version is the teacher using, and which python version are you using?
Try using python version > 3.8